# How do uploaded file public, DOWNLOADING available without authorization?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I upload file like this:

```
    if (isset($_FILES[$name])) {
        $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

        //Insert a file
        $file = new Google_DriveFile();
        $file->setTitle($_FILES[$name]['name']);
        $file->setMimeType($_FILES[$name]['type']);
        $file->setParents(array('imgs'));

        $insertedFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name']),
            'mimeType' => $_FILES[$name]['type']
        ));

        return $insertedFile;
    }
```

Get `insertedFile` as this:

```
Array
(
    [kind] => drive#file
    [id] => 1sASTlgG7IFzcZyTUihp53uJbppFtxLs_GK_V2jYwapE
    [etag] => "vGmlhiWxP02tugPmRvLynwC_A0Y/MTM2NjE4NTYyNzQwOQ"
    [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1sASTlgG7IFzcZyTUihp53uJbppFtxLs_GK_V2jYwapE
    [alternateLink] => ...
```

But when i go to selfLink, i get an error

```
{
  ...
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

What is the correct way to get uploaded file without any kind of authorization? Looks like file is only available through the API.

Comment: The error looks like you are over the max. upload limit.

Comment: Perhaps you exceeded some limit and can no longer download any files from your account without authenticating yourself?

Comment: no, i dont rich upload limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download the content, make an authenticated request to the download URL.

```
// Get the contents of the file.
$request = new Google_HttpRequest($file->downloadUrl);
$response = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($request);
$content = $response->getResponseBody();
```

Comment: sry, im tolking about downloading. i thought uploading was successfull

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Are you trying to download the file contents? If so, don't use selfLink. selfLink responses with file's metadata.